# How do I keep an array reference through closure?

Tags: javascript, arrays, closures, pass-by-reference

Quick question that i seem unable to google...

I'm wondering how to keep an array reference through closure. I think.
Im using AngularJS but raw JS has the same behaviour in my trials.
Context: think of a memory game where you match two images. When two selected tiles mismatch, they flip back but only after showing the selected images. So I want to delay the flip.
I have an array that i .filter to a new array.

```
$scope.selectedTiles = $scope.tiles.filter($scope.filterSelected);
```

An aside: This new array; does it only contain references or copies of data? MDN says

> constructs a new array of all the values for which callback returns a true value.

Not very clear imo. My conclusion is they are references.
Anyways...

This selectedTiles is sent to a closure in order to keep its references. Only it doesnt.

```
flipSelectedTiles = function (selection){
    return function(){
        selection.forEach($scope.flipTile);
    }
};
function reset(selection){
    return function(){
        $scope.flipSelectedTiles(selection);
    }
}

var resetTiles = reset(filteredTiles);
$timeout($scope.flipSelectedTiles($scope.selectedTiles), $scope.delay);
```

I need this because I intend to wait a while before executing the flipSelectedTiles.
I also need to clear the selectedTiles immediately in case someone clicks another image.

```
selectedTiles.splice(0, $scope.selectedTiles.length);
```

As the timeout fires the array is empty and nothing happens.

How do I keep an array reference through closure?

Edit: here is a fiddle in plain JS http://jsfiddle.net/Tobis/TkjEF/
Edit: added flipSelectedTiles function

Comment: What's `$scope.flipSelectedTiles`?

Comment: I managed to get a working angular version in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tobis/S9dzs/

Diff: the first filtration was replaced by a push to the selectedTiles, and the delay timeout now recieves a function with the filteredSelected instead of the selectedTiles.

It is working better, but it doesnt answer the question if you can maintain a working reference through closure allowing modification the original array. I think Ill rephrase the entire post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are keeping a reference. The problem is you're emptying the array too early, as you noted yourself. I believe you need a *copy* instead:

```
var resetTiles = reset(filteredTiles.slice(0));
$timeout(resetTiles, $scope.delay);
```

Also note that you weren't passing a function to `$timeout`, you were invoking `flipSelectedTiles` immediately (unless `flipSelectedTiles` returns a function).

Comment: sorry, yeah the flipSelectedTiles does return a function:
    $scope.flipSelectedTiles = function (selection){
  return function(){
   selection.forEach($scope.flipTile);
  }
 };
See the new fiddle in OP

Comment: You don't seem to have tried `slice` as I suggested. See http://jsfiddle.net/TkjEF/2/

Comment: And right you are. I did not ignore you, getting angular to work in fiddle was annoyingly painful experience.Thanks for your time!

Comment: I'm glad it worked! I didn't add much explanation, but `slice` can be used to either return a piece of an array, or a copy of the whole array, depending on the parameters passed.